# How to set loader for a promise.all action in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So when I check Redux dev-tools i see that I've received my data and they are a part of the state, but when I try to use conditional rendering it wont render the page and gives error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Global Quote' of undefined !

If I just use this.props.data.TSLA it works fine and the page renders...

When I use this.props.data.TSLA["Global Quote"]["01. symbol"] page won't render! (the keys are strings in the JSON so I need to use square brackets).

I am also using Redux-Thunk !

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { START_FETCH_DATA } from './redux/dataReducer';

class Fetcher extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.START_FETCH_DATA()
}

render() {

const { data, dataLoading } = this.props;

    return (
    <li className="tesla-container">
    { this.props.dataLoading ? 
    (<div className="ticker"> Loading! </div>) 
    : 
    (<div className="ticker">{ 
    this.props.data.TSLA["Global Quote"]["01. symbol"] }</div>) }
    </li>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.data,
        dataLoading: state.dataLoading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        START_FETCH_DATA: bindActionCreators(START_FETCH_DATA, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Fetcher)
```

and here is the reducer + actions...

```
export const dataReducer = (state = {dataLoading: true}, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case "START_FETCH_DATA":
        return {...state, dataLoading: true}
    case "FINISH_FETCH_DATA":
        return {...state, dataLoading: false, data: action.payload}
    default:
        return state;
}};

export const START_FETCH_DATA = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    Promise.all(
        [
        fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=TSLA&apikey=LOL`).then(data => data.json()),
        fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=AMZN&apikey=LOL`).then(data => data.json())
        ]
    )
    .then(([TSLA, AMZN]) => {
        dispatch({ type: "FINISH_FETCH_DATA", payload: {TSLA, AMZN} })
    })
}};
```

DEVTOOLS SCREENSHOT
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Efb9.jpg

Comment: `dataReducer` is a function. why `dataReducer.length === 0 ?` ?

Comment: `data` comes through `props`, yet you are not referencing props at all. That's why the function is literally called `mapStateToProps`

Comment: I would advise to start with the redux documentation. It's very well written https://redux.js.org

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should use the data provided by `redux` in `render()`:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { START_FETCH_DATA, dataReducer } from './redux/dataReducer';

class Fetcher extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.START_FETCH_DATA()
}

render() {
    return (
    <li className="tesla-container">
    { this.props.dataLoading ? 
    (<div className="ticker"> Loading! </div>) 
    : 
    (<div className="ticker">{ 
    this.props.data.TSLA["Global Quote"]["01. symbol"] }</div>) }
    </li>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.data,
        dataLoading: state.dataLoading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        START_FETCH_DATA: bindActionCreators(START_FETCH_DATA, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Fetcher)
```

Comment: I've added the code you wrote since its definitely how it should be. I still get an error though. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Global Quote' of undefined (the page doesnt even render)

Comment: @SoGoddamnUgly if you put the code in https://codesandbox.io I could take a look.

Comment: Hey man i managed to fix my issue. Can you check the answer and tell me if there still anything nonsensical in my code? I learned a lot from you thanks.

Comment: @SoGoddamnUgly looks good; I'd `return Promise.all` though - might be useful someday.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue.

Fixed code below:

```
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dataLoading: state.dataReducer.dataLoading,
        data: state.dataReducer.data
    }
}`
```

instead of

```
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dataLoading: state.dataLoading,
        data: state.data
    }
}`
```